# Memory buildup with presentViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios7, memory-leaks, presentviewcontroller

I have a button click handler that saves an object and then presents another controller. My problem is that with each click the memory allocated increases.

```
  if (success) {
      ALRollsViewController *rollsController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Entry" bundle:nil]instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RollsController"];
      rollsController.camera= selectedCamera;
      [self presentViewController:rollsController
                         animated:YES
                       completion:nil];
  }
```

If I use dismissViewControllerAnimated as opposed to presentViewController:rollsController there is no buildup. Do I need to release the instantiated controller somehow?

Comment: are you dismissing those presented view controllers ?

Comment: no, not sure where this takes place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you expect?
Each click instanticates a new instance of UIStoryboard. Naming convention here is, that a method beginning with the name of the object (name without prefixes) returns a newly created instance of the object.

See and compare to `NSArray arrayWith...` or `NSString stringWith...`

Plus you need an instance of the view controller every time to be presented. 
Both instances are kept until the view controller is dismissed. 
(I am not 100% positive about the UIStoryboard instance to be kept that long, but the newly presented view controller will eat up your heap and a bit of your stack.)

Comment: Ouch. Most of this stuff is like vodoo for me so I guess I expected the presented view to be dismissed automagically. I'm apparently wrong on that. thanks for the naming convention heads up. I'm not sure where I dismiss the presented controller

Comment: Yes and that is for a reason. There is nothing wrong with stacking tons of instances of the same view controller class on each other - if that is what you as a programmer want to do. Aparently you don't so don't forget to dismiss the one that is not longer needed.